# Input binding with numbers

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a nasty problem with input binding.
I had a model with a observable property "capacity" and bind it to an input element.
The type of the input element is "number".
The code looks like this.

```
<input id="capacityInput" data-bind="textInput: Capacity" type="number" class="form-control">
```

The binding works correct on to-source but at to-target I hade a language problem.
The value in my model is "193.8" JS typeof "number".
My OS and browser is on german language.

Firefox shows the correct decimal point for Germany "," but IE not.
Can somebody explain me why, please...

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Internet Explorer:

[image: Internet Explorer]

Comment: i used numeral.js for that, auch usefull for tausendertrenner etc.

Comment: IE doesn't have support for `input type=number`, so something is just doing a toString on the value.